# VFIO - igpu passthrough on Intel 4770 to a qemu virtual machine (Proxmox)

Tags: proxmox

I am running the latest Proxmox (6.3-3 at this time, fully updated) and attempting to passthrough the onboard GPU on my Core i7 4770 CPU to a Windows 10 VM. I have already enabled iommu on the system and also told grub to not let the system claim the device by adding `intel_iommu=on video=efifb:off` to the grub kernel options. I've verified IOMMU is actually available by checking dmesg

```
# dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU -e AMD-Vi
[    0.007556] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000D88C33C8 0000B8 (v01 INTEL  HSW      00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.083595] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.180445] DMAR: Host address width 39
[    0.180446] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0
[    0.180449] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap c0000020660462 ecap f0101a
[    0.180449] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed91000 flags: 0x1
[    0.180451] DMAR: dmar1: reg_base_addr fed91000 ver 1:0 cap d2008020660462 ecap f010da
[    0.180452] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000d8842000 end: 0x000000d884efff
[    0.180452] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000db000000 end: 0x000000df1fffff
[    0.180454] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0xfed91000 IOMMU 1
[    0.180454] DMAR-IR: HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed91000
[    0.180455] DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.
[    0.180831] DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode
[    0.874497] DMAR: No ATSR found
[    0.874527] DMAR: dmar0: Using Queued invalidation
[    0.874531] DMAR: dmar1: Using Queued invalidation
[    1.026818] DMAR: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O
```

I've also added the iGPU (and associated audio device) to blacklist to prevent the host OS from claiming it:

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
blacklist i915

# cat /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
options vfio-pci ids=8086:0412 disable_vga=1
```

Finally, I setup a new Windows 10 VM on my host along with the q35 chipset and uEFI (OVMF) BIOS as this is apparently the most "compatible" way to pass through hardware. I've also got an external screen plugged into the HDMI port of my Proxmox host. I understand when the VM boots up, I should see this screen come to life. The qemu config file of the VM is below:

```
agent: 1
balloon: 0
bios: ovmf
boot: order=virtio0;ide2;net0
cores: 4
efidisk0: local-1tb-nvme-thinpool:vm-118-disk-1,size=4M
hostpci0: 00:02,pcie=1,x-vga=1
ide2: none,media=cdrom
machine: q35
memory: 4096
name: VFIOtest
net0: virtio=52:D7:02:CA:B6:2E,bridge=vmbr0,firewall=1
numa: 0
ostype: win10
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=cd9d41e9-d8c2-465e-94dc-798aa8e517e2
sockets: 1
virtio0: local-1tb-nvme-thinpool:vm-118-disk-0,backup=0,discard=on,size=60G
vmgenid: 2cb8ce5e-5dda-4870-9cf3-774bb025057f
```

Once I've done that I can boot the VM. As soon as I boot the VM, the screen goes to standby indicating no signal. I can however then RDP into the system and I see that the Intel HD Graphics 4600 is visible in device manager. So I installed the latest drivers from the Intel website. Unfortunately, the device will not start and shows an exclamation mark next to it. The Device Status shows

`Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)`

Unfortunately, the `code 43` error just means something is wrong, it isn't very specific on what is causing this.

Just out of curiosity, I created a Ubuntu 20.04 VM with UEFI Bios and passed my GPU through to it and it works perfectly (I can see the desktop etc on the monitor that is plugged into the motherboard).

Not too sure what to try from this point on - any assistance on where to continue fixing this would be useful.

**EDIT**: I have given up on this after wrestling with it for a while. It appears to be an issue within Windows 10 that causes this. I setup a Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop VM (with q35 chipset) and passed through my iGPU to it - works right away (I can see the Ubuntu desktop coming up on the monitor plugged into the motherboard via HDMI).

Comment: is proxmox also installed as uefi?

Comment: Doing the opposite of trying to keep the card pristine is worth a shot.  *Do* use the device for `efi-framebuffer`, then `unbind` it via *sysfs* before manually binding it to `vfio-pci`. The difference being some extra reset code, ruling out your host UEFI doing something to the card that is later confusing windows.

Comment: @djdomi - yes my proxmox is installed and booted as uefi (I verified it by checking the output of `efibootmgr -v`)